# agroup 2 OR after and codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter

Greeting!, I have a little problem with this sql query, I need join several  "OR" on a parenthesis.. And i don't know how to do that.. So this is the example:

```
SELECT a.a1, b.b1, c.c1 from a inner join b on a.a1=b.b1 inner join c on a.a1 = c.c1 where c.c2='t' and ( a.a1 like %XXXX% or b.b1 like %XXXX% )
```

And this is what i wrote on codeigniter code

```
$this->db->select("a.a1, b.b1, c.c1");
$this->db->where("c.c2",'t');
$this->db->like("a.a1", $match);
$this->db->or_like("b.b1", $match);
$this->db->join("b","a.a1 = b.b1",'inner');
$this->db->join("c","a.a1 =c.c1",'inner');
```

But this is the output, and obviously isn't what i want

```
SELECT a.a1, b.b1, c.c1 from a inner join b on a.a1=b.b1 inner join c on : a.a1 = c.c1 where c.c2='t' and a.a1 like %XXXX% or b.b1 like %XXXX%
```

Comment: Why not just write the query manually and use `$this->db->query()` instead of using active records? That would allow to write however you chose.

Comment: @mituw16 Maybe that is company standard or maybe just want to learn.

Comment: well, that was what i did, but i don't know if that was the right way to solve the problem.. Or there are another way for write that with codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select("a.a1, b.b1, c.c1");
$this->db->where("c.c2",'t');
$this->db->group_start(); // (
$this->db->like("a.a1", $match);
$this->db->or_like("b.b1", $match);
$this->db->group_end(); // )
$this->db->join("b","a.a1 = b.b1",'inner');
$this->db->join("c","a.a1 =c.c1",'inner');
```

Comment: I do it, but dont work. get a error: 
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method CI_DB_postgre_driver::group_start()